# Prevent Struts from escaping labels

Tags: java, internationalization, struts

In my resources file I have form labels like so:

`global.background.first_name.label=Pr&eacute;nom:`

And inserting them in the JSP:

`<s:label for="firstName" key="global.background.first_name.label" />`

How do I get it to come up as `Prénom:`, not `Pr&eacute;nom:`?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up rewriting the labels with standard HTML and insert the keys with like so:

`<label for="firstName"><s:text name="global.background.first_name.label"/></label>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at top of your jsp file.

`<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>`

It will encode this é to é.